# Send binary data from Android in Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, android-canvas

I'm trying to send `canvas.toDataURL()` to Facebook via the Javascript API on an Android 2.3 browser, and for some reason it doesn't seem to work. I've tried sending using the `XMLHttpRequest.sendAsBinary` but I keep getting

> {\n   \"error\": {\n      \"message\": \"(#324) Requires upload file\",\n      \"type\": \"OAuthException\",\n      \"code\": 324\n   }\n}

The problem is that this works fine in Google Chrome's desktop browser. How can I send form binary data via Javascript on Android?

[Sample code here](http://pastebin.com/7FCiTTaS)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem... It works with Android 4.0.x but not with versions 2.3 and 3.0. Have you found a solution ?

Comment: My workaround... sending it to PHP and forcing download from there...it works

Comment: While this isn't an answer, you might want to install fiddler2.com and use the mobile proxy server.  This would let you monitor network traffic and look for differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,

It seems to be device specific and I have used a work around of both Ajax and form submission based on device

Answer (score 0):

The pastebin has been removed. But why not check the new FormData HTML5 feature. It's let you send a form by Ajax (a real form like it was a normal ) : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

You can send a file as usually.